# How to split files?

Tags: python

```
import os
import shutil

def split_files_by_brackets(directory_path):
    if not os.path.exists(directory_path):
        print("Указанный путь не существует.")
        return
    
    bracket_files_path = os.path.join(directory_path, 'files_with_brackets')
    non_bracket_files_path = os.path.join(directory_path, 'files_without_brackets')

    os.makedirs(bracket_files_path, exist_ok=True)
    os.makedirs(non_bracket_files_path, exist_ok=True)

    for filename in os.listdir(directory_path):
        file_path = os.path.join(directory_path, filename)
        if os.path.isfile(file_path):
            if '(' in filename or ')' in filename:
                shutil.move(file_path, os.path.join(bracket_files_path, filename))
            else:
                shutil.move(file_path, os.path.join(non_bracket_files_path, filename))

    print("Файлы успешно разделены.")
```

is this the most optimal way?

Comment: could you provide some more explanation about what you want to achieve?

Comment: It *appears* that what you are trying to do is move all files in a directory to one of two subdirectories based on the files' names. If that is the case, then say so in order that people can read the code in light of what you say you want to do. So I am just guessing what you want to do by looking at the code. Clearly all code does something but to say whether it is even correct let alone optimal requires *knowing with certainty* what it is supposed to do.

Comment: What is the definition of optimal here?